# ckeditor - javascriptspellcheck plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I am trying to integrate [javascriptspellchecker](http://www.javascriptspellcheck.com/HTML_Editor_SpellChecker_in_JavaScript) into a web page with [ckEditor](http://docs.cksource.com/Main_Page) (note I am using ckeditor version 3.6). I would like to replace the default spellcheck and SCAYT (spell check as you type) plugins with new custom plugins that use javascriptspellcheck.

I have created a plugin following the example from the javascriptspellchecker website but it doesn't work properly. The javascriptspellchecker taked the id of the textarea and runs a spellcheck on it's value (or attaches event handlers to spellcheck after input when chosing SCAYT). The problem is, when I alter the text in a ckEditor instance, the hidden textbox doesn't seem to be updated in the background. This means the plugin I have written only checks the original value of the textarea, and the SCAYT doesn't work.

My plugin so far:-

```
(function () {
    //Section 1 : Code to execute when the toolbar button is pressed
    var a = {
        exec: function (editor) {
            $Spelling.SpellCheckInWindow($(editor.element).attr('id'))
        }
    },

    //Section 2 : Create the button and add the functionality to it
    b = 'javascriptspellcheck';
    CKEDITOR.plugins.add(b, {
        init: function (editor) {
            editor.addCommand(b, a);
            editor.ui.addButton("JavaScriptSpellCheck", {
                label: 'Check Spelling',
                icon: this.path + "images/spell.png",
                command: b
            });
        }
    });
})();
```

Does anyone know if it is possible to make a working plugin? Is there a way to force the editor to update the hidden textarea, or is there another DOM element I can pass to the spellchecker?

**Update:**

In case it is useful, the SCAYT version of my plugin uses the following execute function

```
exec: function (editor) {
    $Spelling.SpellCheckAsYouType($(editor.element).attr('id'))
}
```

**Update 2:**

I found a soltion for the normal spell check, I can call editor.UpdateElement() before running the spell check and it works! I'm not sure why though, when I inspect the original textarea with firebug the value doesn't seem to have changed.

New Spellcheck plugin

```
(function () {
    //Section 1 : Code to execute when the toolbar button is pressed
    var a = {
        exec: function (editor) {
            editor.updateElement();
            $Spelling.SpellCheckInWindow($(editor.element).attr('id'));
        }
    },

    //Section 2 : Create the button and add the functionality to it
    b = 'javascriptspellcheck';
    CKEDITOR.plugins.add(b, {
        init: function (editor) {
            editor.addCommand(b, a);
            editor.ui.addButton("JavaScriptSpellCheck", {
                label: 'Check Spelling',
                icon: this.path + "images/spell.png",
                command: b
            });
        }
    });
})();
```

I still can't get SCAYT to work though. I found a [ckeditor plugin](http://alfonsoml.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/onchange-event-for-ckeditor.html) to catch change events, and tried to call the updateElement() funciton again on every change. This doesn't work though, can anyone help?

My SCAYT plugin using the ckeditor onchange plugin:

```
exec: function (editor) {
    editor.on('change', function (e) { this.updateElement(); });
    $Spelling.SpellCheckAsYouType($(editor.element).attr('id'));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After contacting support for JavaScriptSpellcheck, they replied saying "**SCAYT will not work with any editor as it risks injecting junk HTML into your forms**". So the SCAYT plugin for CK Editor is not possible. As in my question update, the code for a working Spell Check in Window plugin for CK Editor (v3.6) is below:

```
(function () {
    //Section 1 : Code to execute when the toolbar button is pressed
    var a = {
        exec: function (editor) {
            editor.updateElement();
            $Spelling.SpellCheckInWindow($(editor.element).attr('id'));
        }
    },

    //Section 2 : Create the button and add the functionality to it
    b = 'javascriptspellcheck';
    CKEDITOR.plugins.add(b, {
        init: function (editor) {
            editor.addCommand(b, a);
            editor.ui.addButton("JavaScriptSpellCheck", {
                label: 'Check Spelling',
                icon: this.path + "images/spell.png",
                command: b
            });
        }
    });
})();
```